# 404 Page when emptying spam or deleting a plugin

Tags: plugins, 404-error, spam

I have recently had a website migrated by my host over to a new server within the same network.

I have now noticed that within the WordPress dashboard, if I try and do any of the following...

```
Empty Spam
Delete Plugin
```

I get a 404 error, I imagine it is something to do with the migration but in terms of tackling my hosts can anyone suggest an area to concentrate on for fixing it?

Answer (score -2):

you should deactivate the plugin(s) first, then delete. i just upgraded to wordpress version 3.8 and everything is okay.